# How i can fix my functions automatic repetition

Tags: python, function, speech-recognition, pyttsx3

**So i have a voice assistant project i use speech recognition and pytsx3, the problem is the functions repetition, so this is my code**

main.py:

```
import possibilities as ps

clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[3].id)
engine.setProperty("rate", 160)
def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()
while True:
    
    rec = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as mic:
        print("Manini listen...")
        audio = rec.listen(mic)
        try:
            text = rec.recognize_google(audio, language='en')
            query = text.lower()
        except Exception as e:
            print("Manini Listen...")   

    
    if 'wikipedia' in query:
        ps.wikipediaSer(query)

    elif "say" in query:
        ps.sayrep(query)
        
    elif 'open youtube' in query:
        ps.openyoutube()
```

possibilties.py:

```
def wikipediaSer(query):
    speak('Searching Wikipedia...')
    query = query.replace("wikipedia", "")
    results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences = 2)
    speak("According to Wikipedia")
    print(results)
    speak(results)

def sayrep(query):
        say_text = query.replace("say", "")
        speak(say_text)
        
def openyoutube():
    speak("Here you go to Youtube\n")
    webbrowser.open("youtube.com")
```

so when I execute the project and say a command Wikipedia par example, Wikipedia code repet 5 times. how I can fix this repetition please.

Comment: May I know where you're breaking out from your indefinite while loop?

Comment: i didn't out from the while loop all the code in the loop

Comment: elif "what is" in query or "who is" in query:
        ps.whatis(query)

    else:
        pass

Comment: this is the last 3 linesin the file i